# Formula to move arc path around circle

Tags: trigonometry

[Updated picture arc path around circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlHVI.png)
So that the object following the arc path always starts and ends on the intersecting point between arc path and circumference of containing circle.

I simply can't figure out the maths to rotate the arc path as it moves around the circle. As shown in my new awesome picture...

Thank you

Comment: Your link displays nothing...

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that you'd like to have the equation of the thinner white line? Maybe it would be useful to work in polar coordinates, so that $r=r(\theta)$. If you stretched the circle to a line, what kind of equation would that give to you?

Comment: @YuiToCheng I had the same problem using IE, but Firefox works.

Comment: @PaulFrost I can see it using my phone, but when I try to insert the image into the body, it became invisible again...

Comment: Yeah it shows on mine using dolphin browser on a tablet.

Comment: @MattiP. Yes sir! Polar coordinates works fine for me. I'm working with x and y. Stretched to a line..hmm...isn't it 2*pi*r*180...? Where r would be a portion of the line?

Comment: @MattiP. I can't find any help with this online...rotating an arc around a circle seems to be not a problem. I'm trying to write this as a computer program which converts degrees into radians using sin and cos...x=sin(rad(deg))*r, y=cos(rad(deg))*r

Comment: Perhaps you would like to make this a [hypocycloid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hypocycloid.html). It looks like you want one in which the small circle's radius is a small fraction (perhaps 1/20 or 1/24) of the larger circle's radius.

Comment: @DavidK thank you no that wouldnt work. I need to figure out the arc so it looks like it's bouncing because there are regular points I need it to land on.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PedalCurve.html ...I wonder if this would work? If I could figure out what all the symbols mean? Then modify it for a circle instead of eclipse...??

Comment: @DavidK David you have totally and utterly lost me. My maths is ridiculously poor. I don't even know what all those notations mean! Apart from x,y,r and the pi symbol.

Answer (score 0):

I still think a [hypocycloid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hypocycloid.html) could draw a picture like yours. It's just that the examples shown in various web pages don't make the rolling circle small enough.

To adjust where the bounces land in the hypocycloid, just measure the arc distance between the landing points. If the landing points are separated by an angle $\theta_0$ radians on a large circle of radius $R$, then the arc distance between the points is $R\theta_0,$ and you would want to make the small circle's radius $$r = \dfrac{R\theta_0}{2\pi}.$$

---

A different alternative would be to simulate the physics of a ball bouncing against the inside of a cylinder in a rotating frame of reference with no other forces applied. That is, if you were sitting inside the rotating cylinder rotating along with it, and watched a bouncing ball, this is what you might see.

Given a circle of radius $R$ that you want to bounce within,
one way is to choose two points on the outer circle that are farther than you want the distance between bounces to be.
Using polar coordinates (in radians), suppose you want the ball to hit the outer circle at angle $\theta_1$ (so in polar coordinates it hits at the point $(R,\theta_1)$) and then again at angle $\theta_2.$
Let $A$ be the point at polar coordinates $(R,k\theta_1)$ and
$B$ be the point at polar coordinates $(R,k\theta_2)$.

Convert the polar coordinates to Cartesian $x,y$ coordinates.
Develop a parametric equation in $x$ and $y$ coordinates that takes you from $A$ to $B$ at a constant speed.
Convert the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of your equation to polar coordinates and then divide the angle in your polar coordinates by $k$.

Comment: I tried this... where {drss} is a second hand counter from 0 to 360 rising in milliseconds so thought that would act as the larger circle radius...n is the result of dividing 360, the larger radius with r=20, the smaller radius=18, x=({drss})/n*(n-1)*math.cos(r)-math.cos(n-1)*r, y=({drss})/n*(n-1)*math.sin(r)+math.sin(n-1)*r  ...but the smaller circle just travels more or less in a line not a curve...

Comment: and im failing to see how the circle rolls like that. The web page just gives a static formula but doesn't give any clue as to how to make the thing actually move...which value changes??

Comment: The equation you programmed seems unrelated to anything on the linked page. I would use equations (7) and (8), and the time variable is $\phi$. I'll try to spell this out in the answer when I have time.

Comment: ...oh god that's embarrassing!  Well..your advice worked...I plugged in the equations AND IT WORKS!  WOOOOOO!  I just don't understand why! Why is it that x(0)=a and relates to the first point at the maximum radius of the larger circle? Why not 12 & 13 for an n-cusped hypocycloid which is what I was trying to do...

Comment: are you a maths teacher?